# How to prove that $f(x)=ln(sin(x))$ on $(0,1)$ is improperly integrable?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

So I've been trying to prove $f(x)=\ln(\sin(x))$ on $(0,1)$ is improperly integrable. I know that I can prove that the same function is integrable on an interval of $[0,\pi/2]$, let's call the function on this interval g(x), and I think I can use this to prove that the function is improperly integrable on the smaller function. I know that $g(x)$ needs to be improperly integrable on the interval, that $f(x)$ must be integrable on on $[0,c]$ for all $c \in [0,1]$, and that $|f(x)\leq g(x)$ for every $x$ in $[0,1]$. I'm just having a hard time understanding if all these conditions have been met for me to be able to say f is improperly integrable on the interval.

Comment: You know how to integrate $\ln(x)$. Then $\sin(x)$ is approximately $x$ around $x=0$. Try to use some squeezing, by $(1/2)x<=sin(x)<=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: There is problem near $0$, not near $1$. So you have to show that $\int_c^{1}$ has  a limit as $c \to 0$.

Integrating by parts we have $\int_c^{1} \ln (\sin x)dx=x \ln (\sin x)|_c^{1}-\int_c^{1} x\frac {\cos {x}} {\sin x}dx$. The first term has  a finite limit bacause $c \ln (\sin c) \to 0$ as $ c \to 0$. Use the fact that $\frac x {\sin x } \to 1$ as $ x \to 0$ to show that the second term also has a finite limit as $c \to 0$. .

Comment: If OP knows the function is integrable on $[0,\pi/2]$, then OP knows the singularity at $x=0$ doesn't prevent integrability, so there's no need to prove it, I would think.

Comment: So would I also use the fact that $cosx \Rightarrow 1$ as $x\Rightarrow 1$ to say that the second term has a finite limit? I think I'm starting to see it, but I'm a little unsure how to apply this when it's still an integral.

Comment: $\cos x \to  1$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Sorry yeah that's what I meant. So can I just say that the second term is finite after saying that or do I need to add more? It seems that it's just the integral of 1 which would end up as $1-c$ which would obviously be finite, but I don't know if I can say that with the intgeral.

Comment: Continuous functions are Riemann integrable on $[c,1]$. So it is an ordinary Riemann integral, not an improper one, as far as $[c,1]$ is concerned.  @PeverelShipley